# End Sub/Exit Sub if SQL Connection couldnt be opened/found

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

Is there a way to end a sub when the associated SQL connection could not be opened?

For example, my code look like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

But I would like to end the Sub immediately if the connected sql connection couldn't open.

I tried something like this:

```
On Error GoTo Test
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'My Makro

Test:
MsgBox "Error"
End Sub
```

But it seems like that VBA does not see a non-available SQL connection as a "real" error in this context.

Comment: You can use `Exit Sub`

Comment: Doesn't Excel itself offer to stop trying to refresh remaining objects when an error is encountered?

Comment: does refreshing the query table like `activesheet.listobjects(1).querytable.refresh` generate an error.  If so try looping each of them and calling the refresh.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, but unfortunately he also shows me an error when the connection is correct

Comment: That is apparently because you're missing `exit sub` before your `Test:` label.